# How to create a report in SSRS by using another report?

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, dataset

I Had report stateLow.rdl in my project solutions. I need to add one more report to solution named as stateHigh.rdl. The second report structure looks like stateLow.rdl with different datasets. Do I need to develop the structure from scratch or I can use existing report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do is just make a copy of the report you want to clone (stateLow.rdl) using Windows Explorer or whatever and rename it to the new name (stateHigh.rdl). Then in Visual Studio, right-click the `Reports` folder in the Solution Explorer, select `Add -> Existing item...` and add the new report then edit it with my changes.

Comment: If so you should accept the answer (click the green tick) and upvote it so that the next person to view the question knows that the answer solves the problem

Comment: :I am new bie  to stackoverflow any ways Done.Thanks